# Compare multiple lists and return most frequently occurring number column-wise (most common value by index)

Tags: python, list

I have three lists:

```
list1 = [1, 5, 5, 4, 2]
list2 = [1, 4, 5, 3, 4]
list3 = [2, 5, 4, 3, 4]
```

I want to return the most occurring number in each column so for example:

- Column 1 will return 1 since there are {1, 1, 2} and 1 is most occurring
- Column 2 will return 5 since there are {5, 4, 5} and 5 is most occurring
- Column 3 will return 5.

For these lists, I want to get `[1, 5, 5, 3, 4]`.

The list will always have equal length.

Comment: What if there are no 'most occurring' numbers? Are the lists always of equal length?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? Right now you are basically asking us to do your "assignment"

Comment: @zwer yes the list will always have equal length. If there are no recurring number, I need to compare the accuracy of each list (accuracy is produced based on three types of machine learning algorithm from sci-kit library) and choose the number in the column with the highest accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`scipy.stats.mode`:](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html#scipy.stats.mode)

```
from scipy.stats import mode
m = mode([list1, list2, list3])
print(m)
#ModeResult(mode=array([[1, 5, 5, 3, 4]]), count=array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]))
```

And if you want just the most frequent values as a list:

```
print(list(m.mode[0]))
#[1, 5, 5, 3, 4]
```